# Can a non-volatile variable that is delayed assigned to by a method of the class not be read by another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Consider the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

final public class DelayedSet {
    String Val = "Uninitialized";

    public Callable<String> Makegetter(String val) {
        this.Val = val;
        return new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() {
                return DelayedSet.this.Val;
            }
        };
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DelayedSet x = new DelayedSet();
        Callable<String> Foogetter = x.Makegetter("Initialized");
        // Version 1
        try {
            System.out.println(Foogetter.call());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

After running Main, "Initialized" is printed.

Now consider *Variant A*, where `Foogetter` is passed to a new Thread. Will then `Foogetter` also return "Initialized" or is it possible, due to an out-of-date cache condition, for `Foogetter` to return "Uninitialized"?

Also consider *Variant B*, where we have three threads, `T1`, `T2`, and `T3`. `T1`, via futures, submits a `Callable` to `T2`, where `T2` creates `DelayedSet`, calls `Makegetter`, and returns `"Foogetter"` (in quotes since its technically anonymous) via the future back to `T1`. `T1` then takes this result (the `"Foogetter"`), and submits another callable, this time to `T3`, where `T3` calls `"Foogetter"`. For both variants, is it guaranteed that "Initialized" will be returned or can "Uninitialized" ever be returned?

To summarize in psuedocode:

```
T1:
futureT2 = executorService.submit(new Callable {
...
call() {
// Runs in T2
Foo = new DelayedSet;
return Foo.Makegetter("Initialized");
} ...
futureT3 = executorService.submit(futureT2.get());
print(futureT3.get());
```

Coming from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583448/what-can-force-a-non-volatile-variable-to-be-refreshed), I get the impression that one would need to rely on synchronization events to piggy back on, such as a volatile or synchronized block. However, I'm trying to determine the special case to not require volatiles (even via piggybacking), but due to happen-before semantics of thread creation and joining, will not incur any out-of-date cache conditions.

Can anyone clarify what the memory model with regard to threading is, in order to answer the question?

Comment: Better formatting or a flowchart would make this question much more readable.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

Comment: @Alex, I posted the question specifically because I couldn't answer it after reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *Variant A*, I'm going to assume something like

```
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        System.out.println(Foogetter.call());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}).start();
```

In this case, [the JLS has us covered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the started thread.

The

```
this.Val = val;
```

happened within the `Makegetter` invocation which happens-before the invocation of `Thread#start()` which then happens before the invocation of `call` within the started thread. The value returned will always have to be `"Initialized"`.

In *Variant B*, the first thing to note is the memory consistency effect of [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

> Actions taken by the asynchronous computation happen-before actions
>   following the corresponding `Future.get()` in another thread.

By the time `futureT2.get()` returns in `T1`, the `call` invocation in `T2` has happened(-before) and the invocation of `MakeGetter` has already set the value of `DelayedSet.Val`. This change is visible to `T1` which gets the `Callable` and to `T3` which returns this updated value and to `T1` again which retrieves it with `futureT3.get()`.

Comment: Lacking much experience with the spec, personally it's been hard to confidently make claims. Thanks for providing such an authoritative answer.

Comment: Also, given the code handles both variants (for starting and joining/getting threads) would you more strongly state that this is sufficient to be memory consistent in all use cases? Ie, you will never be able to call the result from Makegetter and get "Uninitialized"?

Comment: @bmillare ***If*** the write to `Makegetter` happens-before the read then yes, you will never get `Uninitialized`.  That is why the happens-before relationship is so strong, but you need to prove it satisfies this relationship.